# How to change menu to match image color with PHP

Tags: php

Let's say I have five images:

red, green, blue, purple and orange.jpg

How can I make these change randomly on refresh and make the navigation menu color change based on the image?

I did try but the code I wrote is so laughable that I'd never put it up for anyone to see.

Edit: keep in mind this is taken from another forum and edited for what I tried to do. This was made for testing. Also, inside the maintenance folder where I'm getting my files there is a .jpg image called storage. That's why you see it in the code.

```
    <?php 
//path to the image directory 
$directory = "maintenance/"; 

//get all image files with a .jpg extension. 
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg"); 

// get random image index 
$rand_img = array_rand($images, 1); 

// display the image 
echo '<img src="'.$images[$rand_img].'" alt="" />';
 ?>

<div style="<?php 
if ($rand_img == "storage.jpg")
echo "background: red;"; ?>height: 100%;width:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: off topic - http://www.whathaveyoutried.com?

Comment: show us the code, we cant debug empty air

Comment: Constructive Criticism will be the best way to learn. You should post your code.

Comment: Maybe you want to try the [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) PHP function to randomize (pseudo) your image and menu color?

Answer (score 1):

Get the color:

```
$color = array_rand('red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'orange');
```

Use as the background for DOM element:

```
<div style="background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>;">
   <!-- more html here -->
</div>
```

And yeah, images are completely not required, just use color names.

Comment: Where is the image? He wants them to match.

Comment: If images are just solid colors, he doesn't need them.

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `rand()` you can do something like this:

```
$cols = array('red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'orange');

// rand returns a random number between
$index = rand(0, count($cols));

$backgroundImage = $cols[$index] . '.jpg';
```

Then you'll have to use `$backgroundImage` in your HTML template.